# trouble with join two table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables user and contacts where register user added records using csv along with their id in contacts table.

my table structure

`user`

```
id   name     phone_no  verify
1    sachin   123        yes
2     max     345        yes
3    john     99         yes
```

`contacts`

```
contacts_id   name    phone_no   user_id
     1        xyz     345        1
     2        abc     123        2
     3        john    99         1
```

Result

```
1) search phone_no '123' from contacts table

contacts_id   name    phone_no   user_id
     2         abc     123        2

2) i got my number '123' in 2nd row will check who has my number so got user_id='2'

3) now i have checked whether 'max' (id='2') has phone_no ('123') in contacts table

4) So max phone_no is '345'

contacts_id   name    phone_no   user_id
      1        xyz     345        1
```

5) i got max number '345' which save as 'xyz'(does not matter) with user_id='1' which is       sachin

6) so i just want to get those user who has my number and they have mine.(final Result)

Comment: What is the `contacts` table for? Can't it just connect users (as they already save the `phone_no`)? So structure would be `id, user_id1, user_id2`

Comment: Can you provide desired results?  It is not obvious what you are trying to do, because the table structures seem quite arcane.

Comment: are people in table contacts users too? if yes, is there a way to identify them besides the name? I'm missing a contact_id here

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please show your attempts (don't expect us to write a free-and-ready-to-use solution).

Comment: i have provided the code and actual requirement in brief. hope u will help with that. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: should i expect your help ?? bcoz i didn't get any kind of help from anybody.

Comment: Are you sure your example is right? For example, the number 123 belongs to user_id 1, whose name is **sachin**, right? But in table ```contacts```, it's associated with user *abc* and user_id 2. Now, user_id 2 is not *sachin* nor **abc**, but **max**. So, which one is it?

Comment: yes it is right...so i got two user where both user has their number . so if i check with user sachin then i need to fetch max only. this is it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to redesign your schema, because (as far as I can tell) you have a master user table, and you have a feature that allows a user to add other users as his contacts, so you need to keep track of which users are contacts to which other users.

Table contacts doesn't need to hold names or numbers. That data must always come from the users table to ensure consistency.

**users**

```
id   name     phone_no  verify
1    sachin   15123        yes
2    max      26345        yes
3    john     37345        yes
4    peter    48345        yes
5    sam      59345        yes
```

**contacts**

```
relation_id  relation_owner   relation_target
1            1                2 
2            1                3
3            2                3
4            2                4
5            2                5
6            3                1
```

That way, the question you're looking to answer would be solved by the following query

```
select u1.name as me, 
       u2.name as contact
from   users u1 
join contacts c1 on u1.id=c1.relation_owner
join contacts c2 on c2.relation_owner=c1.relation_target and   c2.relation_target=c1.relation_owner
join users u2 on c2.relation_owner=u2.id
where u1.id=:userid
```

Now, if I try to do the same with your schema.

user

```
id   name     phone_no  verify
1    sachin   123        yes
2     max     345        yes
```

contacts

```
id   name    phone_no   user_id
1    xyz     345        1
2    abc     123        2
```

**Edit** After your clarifications

To get the contacts for user 1 (sachin)

```
select u1.name as me, 
       u2.name as contact 
from user u1 
join contacts c1 on u1.phone_no = c1.phone_no
join user u2 on c1.user_id=u2.id
where user.id=1
```

To get the contacts for user sachin who, in turn, have sachin in their contacts

```
select u1.name as me, 
       u2.name as contact 
from user u1 
join contacts c1 on u1.phone_no = c1.phone_no
join user u2 on c1.user_id=u2.id
join contacts c2 on u2.phone_no = c2.phone_no and c2.user_id=u1.id
where u1.id=1
```

I reccomend creating an index on contacts.phone_no, and a unique index on users.phone_no to enhance your queries.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that register user will upload their contacts using csv. So i have attached their user_id with those contacts. So i can not modify contacts like your example. I appreciate your example but not match to my result. Please check my code only last join gives me raw result.

Comment: ok, so my guess seems right. The user_id on the contacts table is the relation_owner, whereas the phone_no is the key to find the relation_target in the users table.

Comment: exactly i am facing the same problem. I got the list who has my number but when i run my query it shows schema is ambiguous. this is the problem. please help me out.

Comment: The last query in my edited answer should run fine. Can you add more rows to your example? That would also help

Comment: i have updated my question. please check hope u will get the idea. what i need exactly. and reply similar with my code.

Comment: the above result gives me only those who has my number but it is an obvious that they should have my number. that is missing.